# Unable to display dynamic Dojo Combobox despite adding required resources

Tags: dynamic, combobox, dojo

I am not able to display Dojo Combobox as explained in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/cswing/DLNNc/) fiddle. I have added references of Dijit.js, Dojo.js, Ready.js and memory.js. My script gets executed as I verified by putting an alert but the Combobox simply doesn't show up. What am I missing?

Following is my html:

```
<div id="stateSelect"></div>
```

Following is my JS script

```
<script>
require(["dojo/store/Memory", "dijit/form/ComboBox", "dojo/ready"],function(Memory, ComboBox){
var ss = 'Abas Store, Accounts';
ss = ss.split(',');
var data = [];
dojo.forEach(ss, function(item, idx) {data.push({id: idx,name: item});});
var stateStore = new Memory({data: data});
var comboBox = new ComboBox({name:  "select",value: "Select...",store: stateStore,searchAttr: "name"},"stateSelect");
});
</script>
```

Following JS references are added and each one of them is accessible:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/webapp/js/dojo/1.9.2/dojo/dojo.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/webapp/js/dojo/1.9.2/dojo/ready.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/webapp/js/dojo/1.9.2/dojo/store/memory.js></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/webapp/js/dojo/1.9.2/dijit/form/ComboBox.js"></script>
```

Edited to show snapshot after "Dimitri M"  reply(referred from my comments):
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm seeing several things here that are not right:

The first thing is that you only need to load the AMD loader (`dojo.js`), all other files are loaded automatically by it, so this means you can remove:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="/webapp/js/dojo/1.9.2/dojo/ready.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/webapp/js/dojo/1.9.2/dojo/store/memory.js></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/webapp/js/dojo/1.9.2/dijit/form/ComboBox.js"></script>
```

---

The second thing I notice (also in the example you're referring to) is that it's missing the proper event to wait for the DOM to load. You should replace `dojo/ready` by `dojo/domReady!`. This will make sure that the callback is only loaded if the DOM is loaded.

If you don't wait for the DOM, then your script might not find the div `#stateSelect`, and then the grid won't load (I think this is your problem).

---

I also have a recommendation (not a bug), you should not use `dojo.forEach()` if you're using a new version of Dojo, that syntax is actually deprecated and should be replace by the `dojo/_base/array` module which has a similar [`forEach()`](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.9/dojo/_base/array#1_9dojo__base_array_forEach) function.

But what you need is not the `forEach()` function, but the [`map()`](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.9/dojo/_base/array#1_9dojo__base_array_map) function to map your array of Strings to an array of objects.

---

I updated the example you used with the recommendations I gave, which you can find [here](http://jsfiddle.net/g00glen00b/6K756/).

Comment: I managed to get output but its not at all what I wanted. I have added snapshot of output, I dont have one but three controls and two of them are readonly(please see snapshot I just added to my original question. I am implementing this in Yii 1.1.12 application and this is my first Dojo ... Any suggestions...

Comment: @FaisalKhan, you need to include dijit.css, that is what transforms those three elements into one combobox.

Comment: Many thanks @Dimitri M for your detailed explanation. Thanks Matt R for pointing out the problem.